# How do I make typographic symbols work with ODBC queries like sqlExecute?

Tags: sql, r, odbc

While using ODBC for R, I realized that it does not work with typographic symbols like ®.

```
test <- c("Marks®")
sqlq <- "SELECT * FROM SQL_TABLE WHERE name = (?)"
retrieve <- sqlExecute( con, sqlq, test, fetch = TRUE)
```

When I ran the retrieve variable, it does not return any values, although there is a Marks® inside my SQL_Table. If it is not possible to retrieve results with ® (or any other symbols in it), is there a way to detect such symbols and delete them from the variable/data frame before retrieving from the SQL table?

Comment: `name = (?)` might be non-standard syntax; I would expect either `name = ?` or `name in (?)`, do the other two work any differently? Also, is the `name` field *entirely* that string, or is it a part of the string, suggesting `name LIKE '%Marks%'`?

Comment: I've tested this in SQL Server, Postgres, and SQLite, and it works fine, so there must be something else going on. (Granted, I'm using `DBI` and `odbc`, not `RODBC`, so that might be a reason why it's working for me and not for you.)